# TypeScript not flagging incompatible generics

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types, interface

I'm building out a pluggable interface/class architecture so that an "output" can plug into an "input". I quickly discovered that TypeScript isn't throwing any warnings or errors when I use a compatible interface but with an incompatible generic. Is there something I'm doing wrong, something more I can do to force correct checking, or is this simply not supported? TypeScript 2.9.2

```
interface IValueA {
  fooA(): void;
}

interface IValueB {
  barB(): void;
}

interface ISomethingA<T> {
  goToB(thing: ISomethingB<T>): void;
}

interface ISomethingB<T> {
  goToA(thing: ISomethingA<T>): void;
}

interface ISomethingAS extends ISomethingA<string> {}
interface ISomethingAN extends ISomethingA<number> {}

interface ISomethingBS extends ISomethingB<string> {}
interface ISomethingBN extends ISomethingB<number> {}

export class SomethingA<T> implements ISomethingA<T> {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingB<T>): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
}

export class SomethingAN implements ISomethingAN {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingBN): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
}

export class SomethingAS implements ISomethingAS {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingBS): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
}

export class SomethingB<T> implements ISomethingB<T> {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingA<T>): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
}

export class SomethingBN implements ISomethingBN {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingAN): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
}

export class SomethingBS implements ISomethingBS {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingAS): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
}

const a = new SomethingA<IValueA>();
const b = new SomethingB<IValueB>();

const as = new SomethingAS();
const an = new SomethingAN();

const bs = new SomethingBS();
const bn = new SomethingBN();

a.goToB(b); // ISomethingA<IValueA> expects ISomethingB<IValueA> but accepts ISomethingB<IValueB>

as.goToB(bn); // ISomethingAS (ISomethingA<string>) expects ISomethingBS (ISomethingB<string>) but accepts ISomethingBN (ISomethingB<number>)
an.goToB(bs); // ISomethingAN (ISomethingA<number>) expects ISomethingBN (ISomethingB<number>) but accepts ISomethingBS (ISomethingB<string>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want errors, you should actually use generic `T` parameter for something inside `ISomethingA` and `ISomethingB`. If you only pass it as another generic parameter to something else and never actually use it, there are no errors because the type system is structural and the types are compatible.

As it says in the [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--): "In general, you should never have a type parameter which is unused. The type will have unexpected compatibility (as shown here) and will also fail to have proper generic type inference in function calls."

Here is the code that gives errors that you probably are expecting:

```
interface IValueA {
  fooA(): void;
}

interface IValueB {
  barB(): void;
}

interface ISomethingA<T> {
    goToB(thing: ISomethingB<T>): void;
    t: T[];
}

interface ISomethingB<T> {
  goToA(thing: ISomethingA<T>): void;
    t: T[];
}

interface ISomethingAS extends ISomethingA<string> {}
interface ISomethingAN extends ISomethingA<number> {}

interface ISomethingBS extends ISomethingB<string> {}
interface ISomethingBN extends ISomethingB<number> {}

export class SomethingA<T> implements ISomethingA<T> {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingB<T>): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

export class SomethingAN implements ISomethingAN {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingBN): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

export class SomethingAS implements ISomethingAS {
  public goToB(thing: ISomethingBS): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToB", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

export class SomethingB<T> implements ISomethingB<T> {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingA<T>): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

export class SomethingBN implements ISomethingBN {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingAN): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

export class SomethingBS implements ISomethingBS {
  public goToA(thing: ISomethingAS): void {
    console.log("SomethingA", "goToA", thing);
  }
  t = [];
}

const a = new SomethingA<IValueA>();
const b = new SomethingB<IValueB>();

const as = new SomethingAS();
const an = new SomethingAN();

const bs = new SomethingBS();
const bn = new SomethingBN();

a.goToB(b); // error

as.goToB(bn); // error
an.goToB(bs); // error
```